# Create Powerpoint with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, powerpoint

JavaScript cannot create files locally on the clients filesystem. However, I am wondering, if it is possible to somehow create a Powerpoint MIME in a web page (a div or a iframe) from some JSON and then let the UserAgent figure out it is Powerpoint in the expectation that the UserAgent will offer the user the choice to display it as a powerpoint presentation?

Note: The idea here is to be able to take some JSON and make a powerpoint presentation without having to make a request to a Server to create a Powerpoint file.

Comment: Maybe like http://code.google.com/p/jspdf/. Maybe you can use the same approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One JavaScript library that can generate Powerpoint binary files is [PptxGenJS](https://gitbrent.github.io/PptxGenJS/).

Genreally speaking, you can create a link with a data URL that has a Powerpoint MIME type:

```
 data:ms-powerpoint;base64,aGVsbG8gd... // base64-encoded file
```

Run your logic to create a binary Powerpoint file, then base64-encode it (e.g. with `btoa`), and then dynamically generate a link or redirect `window.location` to the data URI.

```
var binaryPPFile = createPowerpointFromJSON(sourceJSON);
window.location = "data:ms-powerpoint;base64," + btoa(binaryPPFile);
```

My hypothetical `createPowerpointFromJSON` function might make calls to the PptxGenJS API, or any other Powerpoint-generating API.

Comment: thanks any tips for what createPowerpointFromJSON would look  like?

Comment: @dublintech I'm afraid I don't. I imagine that the Powerpoint standard is huge and complex, and there are probably no JavaScript libraries for Powerpoint document creation. If you are willing to use PDF instead of Powerpoint, [jspdf]( http://code.google.com/p/jspdf/) is a library for creating PDF documents in JS.

Comment: yeah that seems to be a consensus.  So I don't think anyone will beat your answer so I'll mark it as answered. Thanks.

Comment: This definitely works creating a ppt file but say if I already have a ppt file in xml format, can I prompt the user to download that xml and set the mime type to power point so that power point can open what it had originally saved as XML?