# How to create power point file using xml or javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, netsuite

How to create powerpoint file using xml or javascript, i want to create powerpoint file using javascript, i have some sample code

```
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="true"?>';
xml += '<?mso-application progid="PowerPoint.Show"?>';        
//xml +='<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:p="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:powerpoint">';    
xml +='<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">';
```

Comment: Read [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144346/create-powerpoint-with-javascript), and [Pure JS PowerPoint 97-2003 (PPT) Parser](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-ppt).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `ppt` file inside file cabinet easily. Just you need to have appropriate type name and format. See the below code :

```
var file = nlapiCreateFile('sample.ppt', 'POWERPOINT', xml);
```

> Note : your string xml has to be base64 encoded.

Comment: yes, but what that xml will contain thats my question is

Comment: Probably reverse engineer:
http://www.free-power-point-templates.com/articles/powerpoint-to-xml/

Save the file as XML and analyse how to build it.

Comment: @SachinPrasad xml is nothing but your string value

Comment: @Rockstar will you help me to create the PPT file i will share my code with you

Comment: please share your email id so that i can send you my code